# Change layer path using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3, file-path

I have a QGIS Project with many raster layers. I need to change/repair all paths since I moved the original data to Another disk.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

old_path = r'D:/Somefolder_QGIS_200317'
new_path = r'C:\GIS\Newfolder'

layer.setDataSource(layer.source().replace(old_path, new_path))
```

But im getting error:

> TypeError: QgsRasterLayer.setDataSource(): not enough arguments

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterLayer.html?highlight=qgsrasterlayer#qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer.setDataSource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [PyQGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterLayer.html?highlight=qgsrasterlayer#qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer.setDataSource), you'll see that the function has `not enough arguments`, it miss the `baseName`, `provider` and data provider `options`. The code below works for me. I just take all the same arguments, except the source :

```py
vl = iface.activeLayer()
new_data_source = "/home/me/Desktop/QGIS-Training-Data-2.0/exercise_data/raster/3320C_2010_314_RGB_LATLNG.tif"
base_name = vl.name()
provider = vl.providerType()
options = vl.dataProvider().ProviderOptions()
vl.setDataSource(
    new_data_source,
    base_name,
    provider,
    options
)
```