# How to solve "handle bad layers" for hundreds of cases in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, routing, missing-data

I am getting the "handle bad layers error" in QGIS 2.18 for over 200 hundred cases.

I am not willing to manually change all these layers. **Is there a way to make the program look in a new parent directory where all the files are located?** It seems that I am only able to browse independently for each layer.

I tried recreating the folder structure for the place where the program tells me it's looking for the files, and it did not work.

***I'm using an older version of QGIS because that's where the project was originally created, and I've found that it's the only version that renders it correctly. In contrast to using a newer version of QGIS.

Comment: Try [changeDataSource plugin](https://geogear.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/changedatasourceplugin-plugin-release-2-0/)

Comment: Find your over 200 hundred data source strings in *.qgs project file and replace with text you need.

Comment: This question has been asked before. See this answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/455182/88814

Comment: Thank you, I replaced text for most of them using search and replace in Notepad++, fixed a couple remaining bad layers using the plugin.